# Ajax JQuery html not use function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I make Ajax Request. Success evet function is a div html chance. 
Ajax successful but runFunction function dont run.

```
$("#dashboard").html("<img src='xxxxxx' class='runFunction'>");
```

HTML Code:

```
<div id="dashboard">
  <div class="Loader"><div class="ball-pulse"><div></div><div></div><div></div></div></div>
</div>
```

AJAX Code:

```
function getGuilds() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "includes/ajax/getGuilds.php",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(respo) {
      if (respo.type == "success") {
        $("#dashboard").html("<img src='xxxxxx' class='runFunction'>");
      } else {
        getGuilds();
      }
    }
  })
}
getGuilds();
```

My Function:

```
$(".runFunction").click(function(){
  alert(1);
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you need to change your listener to this:

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).on("click", ".runFunction", function(){
   alert(1);
});
```

The problem is that at the time your run the function `.runFunction` the ajax has not finished or you have not created the element img with class `.runFunction` and does not exist, but when you change the function using the `document` it works even if you create the element after.

Regards!

Comment: This is covered in the duplicate question.